# How to fill result file with not presented columns names?

Tags: python, pandas

I write the result `output` datafrate to file:

```
for key, columns in formats.items():
  output.to_csv('c:/temp/'+filenameshort+'_shopformat_'+key+'.csv', columns=columns, encoding='utf-8', sep="|", index=False, header=False)
```

Where `formats` is:

```
formats = {
    "kids": ['NUM', 'MMYY', 'FIRSTNAME', 'ADDRESS', 'EMAIL']
}
```

Problem is that dataframe `output` does not have all columns that are in `formats.kids`. It gives me an error:

```
KeyError: "['ADDRESS'] not in index"
```

How to create file with all columns from `formats.kids`?

The `output` has:

```
NUM AGE MMYY
```

Result should be:

```
 NUM AGE MMYY FIRSTNAME ADDRESS EMAIL
 1    18  1212
```

Comment: try just `for key in formats.keys():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUYC, you want to add null columns to your df, you can try:

```
for key, columns in formats.items():
    for col in columns:
        if col not in output.columns:
            output[col]=np.nan
    output.to_csv('c:/temp/'+filenameshort+'_shopformat_'+key+'.csv', columns=columns, encoding='utf-8', sep="|", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, the same issue, I load CSV and set names for columns. There are 10 columns. Then I check if column has FULLNAME and split field on two and rewrite current datadrame. It has 12 columns.

I get this error:
`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: I'll need more details, perhaps ask another question